# Which HttpUtility can support all the symbol on keyboard,able to write style html and support different language(japanese,veitnam,englishand thai)?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, url-encoding

I am using extjs interface and pass in to C# to save string ,but when saved it become other symbol like save symbol "!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?" it will become other symbol to represent them,i am using code below to try accepted all symbol,but still got some symbol cannot support,i confuse with this.hope can share yours exp to me thanks.

my extjs code:

```
msg: decodeURI(Ext.getCmp('txt').getValue())
```

or

```
msg: encodeURI(Ext.getCmp('txt').getValue())
```

to my C# code:

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Request.Params["msg"])
```

or

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Request.Params["msg"])
```

or
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.Params["msg"])

or

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Params["msg"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are sending and receiving messages in UTF-8.

Comment: i nid to decoding all the symbol,and i not sure which HttpUtility is suit to use.

Comment: now i using HTMLDecode and  this special character"%" cannot to pass and unable to put <font color=blue>

Comment: like an example string ="<font color=blue>test(ทดสอบ)!@#$%^&*(){}|[]\:";'<>?,./". which one is better to decode on this string.